# Edit an HTML file using PHP

Tags: php, html

I have a simple form where you can upload an html file, its structure looks like this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="he" xml:lang="he" dir="rtl">

<head>
  <title>test</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../Styles/cssreset-min.css" type="text/css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../Styles/page_styles.css" type="text/css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../Styles/style.css" type="text/css"/>   
</head>

<body id="start">

  <img src="../Images/cover.jpg" class="images" alt="Image 1"/>

</body>

</html>
```

I'm interested in the server-side coding of editing the HTML file, how do I load it, find the img tag and replace it with `<svg>` tag (for example) and save the html file with the same name and extension.
I've tried a number of times but I seems to get confused with with all the different methods out there.
This solution needs to be cross-browser compatible and don't use any dependency if possible, e.g. I tried using <kbd>RecursiveTreeIterator</kbd> once and my hosting company was blocking it from running.

Thanks

Comment: Hi, what you need is a good html parser.

Comment: Server-side there's no browser involved.  The HTML is just a text file, and at a purely technical level would be edited like any other text file.  What makes it different is that it's text formatted in a specific way (hopefully).  I imagine what you're looking for is some kind of DOM parser which can load the HTML, modify it, and save it.

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.I would suggest that you find a development forum (perhaps [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/)?) to work out generalities. Then, when you have specific coding issues, come back to StackOverflow and we'll be glad to help.

Comment: Sourabh, I tried a couple but couldn't select the tags and replace them. Could you help with that?

David, I know all that but since i'm posting here it means I tried without success.

Comment: @Jay, of course there are many answers, I'm satisfied with any that won't cause errors on hosting company servers like `RecursiveTreeIterator`.

Comment: @odedta: `"but since i'm posting here it means I tried without success"` - Maybe you could include at least *some* relevant information about the problems you encountered so people could help with that?  If you're asking how to parse/edit HTML, then the answer is to use an HTML/DOM parser.  If you don't want that answer, then ask a more specific question.

Comment: @David, I think i'll stick with my original post, you don't have to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In general:**

To load any file from local then process the content and save the result you need

1- load the file to server side

2- process the content

3- save the results in server side and give the client a link to download it

so you can create a new file **(pars.php)**
and put this code in it, as you see it has comments to explain you each command

php code is just a simple example, you can improve it

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <form class="public" action="<?php echo "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]"; ?>" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <p><label for="file">File Name:</label> <input type="file" name="file" id="file" /></p>
    <br/>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Parsing" name="sendData"/></p>
    </form>

</body>
</html>

<?php
//test if the file is selected
if(!isset($_POST['sendData'])) exit;
//get file name
$filename = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
//be sure this file is html file
$ext = explode('.', $filename);
if($ext[1] != 'html'){
    echo '<br>bad file type, it must be html file';
    exit;
}
//upload the file to temp area
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
//read the file
$file = @fopen($filename, 'r');
if($file === false){
    echo 'Error when reading the file';
    exit;  
}
//reading line by line
$output ='';
while (($line = fgets($file)) !== FALSE) {
    $output .= str_replace('<img', '<svg', $line);
}
fclose($file);
//write the new file
$result = file_put_contents($filename, $output);
echo $result;
if(!$result){
    echo 'faild';
}else{
    echo 'success <br/>';
    $load_link = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
    $load_link = str_replace('pars.php', '', $load_link); 
    $load_link .= $filename;   
    echo '<a href='.$load_link.'>See the results</a><br>';
}


?>
```

Comment: Finally! a simple method that works! Thanks a lot Mohammad, your script is perfect for me!

Comment: Hello again Mohammad, I have a question about your code: why are you using `@` in your line: `$file = @fopen($filename, 'r');`, what is that for?

Comment: @odedta you can see here http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php

Comment: Lol! what a coincidence, I was trying stuff with my project and I got this silly error you wrote `Error when reading the file` and I tried to find about `fopen` error handling, just read your post and you solved it. Great timing -_^

Answer (score 8):

Are you looking for something like this ?

```
$html=file_get_contents($html_file);
$img_tag= strip_tags($html, '<img><img/>');
$svg_tag='<svg>...';
$html=str_replace($img_tag,$svg_tag,$html);
file_put_contents($html_file,$html);
```

See [strip_tags](https://php.net/strip_tags)

Comment: Warning: preg_replace(): Unknown modifier ']'

Comment: I've updated my answer, much easier with `strip_tags()`

Comment: I've tried that, for some reason the `<img>` tag wasn't replaced but the file was overwritten since Notepad++ asked me if I want to reload the file.

Comment: I'm using xampp for testing by the way, is there any setting I should know of?

Comment: try and print the output of `$img_tag`, I'm sorry Oded, but you're gonna have to do the debugging yourself. If my answer was helpful, please accept it as an answer or at least vote up, thanks.

Comment: I get `string(94) " test  Image 1 "` - It took the title text and the alt attribute of that `<img>` tag. This is exactly why I posted this question!!! nothing seems to work and this is a pretty simple request.

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you just generate  or  tag by PHP?
When I do it really silly and easy, it's going look like this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="he" xml:lang="he" dir="rtl">
<head>
  <title>test</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../Styles/cssreset-min.css" type="text/css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../Styles/page_styles.css" type="text/css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../Styles/style.css" type="text/css"/>   
</head>

<body id="start">
<?php
  if($something == "img") {
      echo "<img src="../Images/cover.jpg" class="images" alt="Image 1"/>";
  } else {
      echo "<svg src="../Images/cover.jpg" class="images" alt="Image 1"/>";
  }
?>
</body>
```

Comment: Because I have a form where people upload an ePub, I extract all the HTML files from it and I want to change their content according to their form input.